# Why Apache IoTDB failed to extend region of cluster Version 1.0.0?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

```
Msg: 1003: ConfigNode failed to extend Region because there are not enough DataNodes
```

I tried to expand cluster Version 1.0.0 of Apache IoTDB and the action failed with an error reported: "Msg: 1003: ConfigNode failed to extend Region because there are not enough DataNodes". What does this error mean and what should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the number of ConfigNode you set in Apache IoTDB. Is the number of ConfigNode greater than the number of available DataNode? If so, creating new available DataNode and relating them to coresponding ConfigNode will do the job.